# R - Time-efficient way of selecting identical rows present in a list of matrices over a defined threshold

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, compare, row

I have a list with 68 matrices. Each matrix is basically an edgelist, consisting of three columns and thousands of rows. The first two columns named Node1 and Node2 respectively, contain gene names. Each row represents an edge in the graph, an interaction between genes. The third column contains the weights for each edge.

The objective is to obtain a final table where the edges that are present in 75% or more of the matrices, and have different weights, are collapsed into a single row. The weight of each final edge will correspond to the mean of the weights of the identical edges.

I would like to know a more time-efficient code for the comparison of large matrices with milions of rows.

## Example

1. Matrices

   ```
   edgelist1<-matrix(data = c("ABCD1","EFGH1","DFEC","JEKC4",0.1314,1.1231),nrow = 2,ncol = 3,dimnames = list(c(),c("Node1","Node2","Weight")))
   edgelist1

   edgelist2<-matrix(data = c("ABCD1","DEIR3","CGESL","DFEC","KMN3","PME2",1.7564,0.6573,0.5478),nrow = 3,ncol = 3,dimnames = list(c(),c("Node1","Node2","Weight")))
   edgelist2

   edgelist3<-matrix(data = c("ACCD1","DEIR3","GUESL","DFEC","KMN3","PMKE2",1.264,0.8573,0.7458),nrow = 3,ncol = 3,dimnames = list(c(),c("Node1","Node2","Weight")))
   edgelist3

   edgelist4<-matrix(data = c("KPF2","NDM1","GUESL","ABCD1","KMN3","PMKE2","LTRC5","DFEC",1.142,0.9273,0.1358,0.3456),nrow = 4,ncol = 3,dimnames = list(c(),c("Node1","Node2","Weight")))
   edgelist4
   ```
2. List

   ```
   list<-list(edgelist1,edgelist2,edgelist3,edgelist4)
   ```
3. Desired output

   ```
   finaledgelist<-matrix(c("ABCD1","DFEC","0.7445"),nrow=1,ncol = 3,dimnames = list(c(),c("Node1","Node2","Weight")))
   finaledgelist
   ```

## My code

```
#Combining all edgelists into one
alledges<-do.call(rbind,list)

#Merging column 1 and column 2
alledges<-data.frame(list(Edges=paste(alledges[,1],alledges[,2]),Weights=alledges[,3]))

#Table to see the frequencies of appearance of each edge
as.data.frame(table(alledges$Edge))->frequencies

# Selection of the edges present in 75% or more of the original edgelists
frequencies[frequencies$Freq>=3,]->selection

#Selection of each edge that appears three or more times
alledges[alledges$Edge %in% selection$Var1,]->repeated

#Collapse by edge name and compute mean of the weights
finaledgelist<-repeated %>%
  group_by(Edges) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(Weights=mean(as.numeric(as.character(Weights)), na.rm = TRUE))

#Final edge list as data frame
finaledgelist<-as.data.frame(cbind(Node1=unlist(strsplit(as.vector(finaledgelist$Edges),split=" "))[2*(1:nrow(finaledgelist))-1],Node2=unlist(strsplit(as.vector(finaledgelist$Edges),split=" "))[2*(1:nrow(finaledgelist))],Weights=finaledgelist$Weights))
finaledgelist$Weights<-as.numeric(as.character(finaledgelist$Weights))
```

Comment: So you can assume no edge is present more than once per matrix?

Comment: Yes, each matrix in the list has already been processed and duplicates have been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same approach as missuse, but since you asked specifically about efficiency, here is the `data.table` version

```
list1 <- list(edgelist1, edgelist2, edgelist3, edgelist4) %>% lapply(as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = F)
dt <- rbindlist(list1)

dt[dt[, pct := .N/length(list1), by = .(Node1, Node2)]$pct >= 0.75
   , .(Weight = mean(as.numeric(Weight)))
   , by = .(Node1, Node2)]

#    Node1 Node2    Weight
# 1: ABCD1  DFEC 0.7444667
```

Benchmark

```
f1 <- function(){
list1 <- list(edgelist1, edgelist2, edgelist3, edgelist4) %>% lapply(as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = F)
dt <- rbindlist(list1)

dt[dt[, pct := .N/length(list1), by = .(Node1, Node2)]$pct >= 0.75
   , .(Weight = mean(as.numeric(Weight)))
   , by = .(Node1, Node2)]
}

f2 <- function(){
  do.call(rbind, list1) %>% #bind all metrics together
  as.data.frame %>% #convert to data frame
  group_by(Node1, Node2) %>% #group by nodes
  mutate(n1 = n()) %>% #count members of each group
  filter(n1 >= (0.75 * length(list1))) %>% #filter those that are present in less than 75% of list elements
  summarise(weight = mean(as.numeric(as.character(Weight)))) #get mean weight for those that are left
}

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(f1(), f2())

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
# f1() 1.817024 2.207588  3.715193  2.718768  3.631382  33.88879   100
# f2() 7.789532 9.990557 16.287901 12.058657 15.876705 347.46884   100
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! This will be a good improvement for larger edgelists.

Answer (score 1):

here is an approach using tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

do.call(rbind, list1) %>% #bind all matrices together
  as.data.frame %>% #convert to data frame
  group_by(Node1, Node2) %>% #group by nodes
  mutate(n1 = n()) %>% #count members of each group
  filter(n1 >= (0.75 * length(list1))) %>% #filter those that are present in less than 75% of list elements
  summarise(weight = mean(as.numeric(as.character(Weight)))) #get mean weight for those that are left

#output#
A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups: Node1 [?]
  Node1 Node2 weight
  <fct> <fct>  <dbl>
1 ABCD1 DFEC   0.744
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and your time! It works fine.